# Unable to route to the route I am already on in router.beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm having trouble routing to a route I am already on when specifying a condition in router.beforeEach in my vue application.

The use case for this is that I want to block access to a route, and redirect back to some arbitrary route, which I may already be on when attempting to access the new route.

Here is the relevant code within `router.beforeEach`

```
NProgress.start();
//code removed for brevity    
if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.role)) {
       next({ path: '/' });
}
```

Here are my routes...

```
const routes = [
    { path: "/products", component: Catalogue },
    { path: "/products/:slug", component: Product },
    { path: "/cart", 
      component: Cart, 
      meta: { role: "Customer" } },
    {
      path: "/checkout",
      component: Checkout,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true, role: "Customer" }
    },
    {
      path: "/account",
      component: Account,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true, role: "Customer" }
    },
    { path: "*", redirect: "/products" }
];
```

I would expect that if I am on the route `/products` when I call `next({ path: '/' });` this would route me to `/` which, as it has no direct match would route to the `*` route which subsequently redirects to my `/products` route. Unfortunately this doesn't happen and the app gets stuck and fails to complete the routing successfully.

I can't seem to debug either as after I call `next({ path: '/' });` it doesn't even enter `router.afterEach` or `beforeRouteEnter` on my `Catalogue` component.

What could be going on here?

No errors are logged. Because I have a spinner from `NProgress.start();` the animation gets stuck on spinning and never stops.

Note that this does work correctly when I am starting at a route which is different to `/products`, such as `/products/soylent-megafone.`